# Stored Proc in SSRS returning NULL Values

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, ssrs-2022

I am trying to build a report in SSRS with the help of a stored procedure. However, when I am executing it is showing following:

[Result returned for SSRS report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6C0g.png)

I am using following stored proc:

```sql
ALTER PROC tbl_EmployeeReport 
@CompanyId varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT  test_tblPayrollCode.CompanyId AS CompanyId, test_TblEmployeeHistory.FirstName
FROM     test_TblEmployeeHistory INNER JOIN
                  test_tblPayrollCode ON test_TblEmployeeHistory.CompanyId = test_tblPayrollCode.CompanyId INNER JOIN
                  test_TblEmployeePaySlip ON test_TblEmployeeHistory.SSO = test_TblEmployeePaySlip.EmployeeNo
                  where test_tblPayrollCode.CompanyId=@CompanyId
END
```

I already checked in table and this stored procedure does return the result when correct `CompanyId` is passed.

For testing purpose, I created the stored procedure without any parameter and removed the parameter option from stored proc as well but it is still giving the same results.

Edit: For those whom picture is not visible, result shows a blank table which has same number of rows and columns as is returned by the stored proc when getting executed in database. But the problem is table is blank.